# What will happen if I remove 301 permenant redirect code?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wordpress, http-status-code-301, google-search-console

I have more than 3000 **301 redirect** in my blog. Its now more than 6 months. Now I want to remove them, but the problem is I don't know what will happen If I do it.

- Will search engines like Google will show 404 errors again in
  webmaster?
- What type of problems I will get if I do it.
- How many redirects YOAST SEO plugin can handle? will it affect my site load speed or Time to First byte.

Answer (score 0):

If search engine showing the new urls instead of previous urls. Than there would be no issue in removing the 301 redirect from .htaccess urls.  Only make sure that not found urls not linked from any page.

You won't face any kind of problem until you linked not found urls from any page.

Comment: Do you know about YOAST SEO plugin? how many redirects I can use there? will it affect my site load speed or Time to First byte?